# Convert an ascii string literal to &[u8] in Rust?

Tags: string, rust

How do you convert an ascii string literal (say, "123 458") into a `&[u8]` slice in rust?  Rust has 6? 7? string types, and there is almost no uniformity in what you call to convert between them.

I'm expecting it to be something along the lines of:

```
let array:&[u8] = Ascii("123 456").into_bytes().as_slice().givemetheeffingbufferalready() as &[u8];
```

Please take it on faith that I actually need to do this; I am writing test cases for some file parser code.

Comment: In fact Rust has only two string types, `String` and `str`.

Comment: I don’t know where you got the idea that it has 6 or 7 string types and I don’t know where you got the idea that there is almost no uniformity in conversion calls; while there are still a very few places where not everything has been made consistent, as a general rule everything is very consistent. `std::ascii` is one of the few areas left that could do with a bit of reworking; it’s not the nicest thing to work with, and it’s worth while realising that `Ascii` is the type of a *single ASCII octet*, and that `Vec<Ascii>`/`[Ascii]` become the “ASCII string” types, as it were.

Comment: There are [some rules](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/wiki/Doc-detailed-release-notes#cast-naming-conventions) about the naming of conversions, so we are trying to be as uniform as possible.

Comment: Well, in addition to String and str, you also have C strings, Asii... and of course you can stick characters in other containers, and if you are dealing with file formats that mix ASCII with binary data you're going to have a lot of strings going back and forth to byte arrays and containers of them. I hope there is a more uniform way to do casting in the works; there should not be heterogeneously named to_foo() and from_bar() sprinkled around the library.

Comment: @Chris, thanks for the note about Ascii; I initially thought it was already an array of Ascii characters and not just a single one.

Comment: @dbaupp, thanks for the link; that might help me discover how to do conversions faster in the future!

Answer (score 35):

After much digging through other related answers, and getting corrected by the nightly version of the compiler, I found out it is trivial; you just add a 'b' to your literal:

```
let array:&[u8] = b"123 456";
```

Comment: BTW, your original attempt can be rewritten as `let array = "123456".as_bytes()", it's that simple :) This does not check for asciiness, of course, it will return UTF-8 bytes sequence. If you need a static array, byte literal is the way to go.